# Symfony Ldap - The presented password is invalid

Tags: symfony, ldap

I want to set up an LDAP connection.
But when validating the user, my log shows me:

Authenticator failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at C:\Users\mf\PhpstormProjects\poc-ldap\vendor\symfony\ldap\Security\CheckLdapCredentialsListener.php:104)","authenticator":"Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapAuthenticator"} []

My configuration :

```
Services.yaml :
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true       
        autoconfigure: true   
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'  
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments:
            - '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter'
        tags:
            - ldap
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            -   host: s.co.lan
                port: 389
                options:
                    protocol_version: 3
                    referrals: false
    monolog.logger.ldap:
        class: Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
        arguments: [ '@monolog.logger.ldap' ]
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger, channel: ldap }
```

```
Security.yaml :
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: OU=UTILISATEURS,OU=CO,DC=co,DC=lan
                search_dn: 'mf@test.fr'
                search_password: password
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: mail

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api_login:
            pattern: ^/api/admin/login
            stateless: true
            json_login_ldap:
                check_path: /api/admin/login
                login_path: /api/admin/login
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'mail={username},OU=UTILISATEURS,OU=CO,DC=co,DC=lan'
```

I also did a test in a specific controller: '$this->ldap->bind($userName, $password);' it works.

Comment: Solution :
dn_string: {username}